# Theme ActionBar Tabs with support or ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, xml, themes, actionbarsherlock

I have been trying to theme the `ActionBar` in my app for a couple of days now, but I have not been able to get any result at all. There has to be something very small I am missing.

The following code, however, results in a red `ActionBar`, but the `TabBar` is not styled at all.
If I change the parent of `Theme.PiVi` to another, the `TabBar` is styled in the corresponding theme.

The device I am testing on is an HTC Sensation running Android 4.0.3 (API 15)

I am not overriding the `android:theme` property anywhere else in the manifest.

AndroidManifest.xml (Snipped)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.PiVi">
```

res/values-v14/themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.PiVi" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.PiVi.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.PiVi.ActionBar</item>

        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Widget.PiVi.ActionBar.TabBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Widget.PiVi.ActionBar.TabBar</item>

        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.PiVi.ActionBar.TabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.PiVi.ActionBar.TabText</item>

        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.PiVi.ActionBar.TabView</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.PiVi.ActionBar.TabView</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

res/values-v14/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Widget.PiVi.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFF0000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.PiVi.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFF0000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.PiVi.ActionBar.TabText" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:color">#FFFF0000</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.PiVi.ActionBar.TabView" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFF0000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```